# MySQL can't accept numbers variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm facing this weird problem. The code below does not work. I only get `0` from `Count`. Expected output is `12` from my `12` rows.

```
echo $userid = $row['userid']; // output is 130

mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM client WHERE userid = $userid");
```

However if I replace `$userid` variable with `integer`, it will work:

```
echo $userid = $row['userid']; // output is 130

mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM client WHERE userid = 130");
```

**UPDATE:**

`$row['userid']` value was taken from other column with the column type as `int`.

I need to use variable in query. Please help me and thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

So I test with the code below where I assign `130` to `$test`. It works.

```
$test = 130;
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM client WHERE userid = $test");
```

Comment: to aid with your debugging, have you tried `echo "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM client WHERE userid = $userid"` ?

Comment: I recommend binding the userid to a prepared statement. Among other great things, this will remove the need of solving this weird problem.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "does not work/will work"?

Comment: if it was an int it would work.

Comment: @pala - You mean like this? `echo mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM client WHERE userid = $userid");` The output is `11111`

Comment: no. i dont. i mean exactly what i wrote. echo the query that you are about to execute to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - Does not work = I don't get the query output.

Comment: @pala_ - Yes, I don't get any output.

Comment: you should also add the part which invokes this part, we don't know if that particular value is overwritten somewhere before it lands into that another query execution line

Comment: what do you mean you dont get any output? its echoing a string. of COURSE you get output?

Comment: @pala_ - I have 12 rows. So I'm suppose to get `12` from the `Count`. This is the output I expected.

Comment: You dont understand what i'm saying. You want to echo the query string to see what query is being run. Or in other words, exactly what i wrote in my comment.

Comment: Tried using `$userid=(int)$row['userid']`? And you sure userid column is of type int? In case that may be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has something to do with parameter being of string type, where you need an integer. Also 'count' is a reserved word which may cause an error, not handled by your code. Need to backtick that also.

I suggest to use prepared statements. It is safer, better practice, and hopefully will solve your issue. Example:

```
$userid = $row['userid']; 

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM client WHERE userid =?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $userid);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $district);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```

Documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty awkward:

```
echo $userid = $row['userid']; // output is 130
```

Go ahead and get rid of that `echo` statement.